# "Unanswered" total is very high

Tags: bug, status-completed, unanswered-questions

The total question indicator for the "Unanswered" tab is 2 to 3 times higher than the actual number of questions displayed (by multiplying the number of pages with questions per page). Some examples:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered): 833,807 vs 292,100 (5842 pages of 50 questions)
- [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered): 6,252 vs 2,145 (143 pages of 15 questions)
- [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered): 2,125 vs 945 (63 pages of 15 questions) - this is where I noticed it

Maybe it is counting questions and answers for the unanswered questions?

Comment: (And it seems the numbers are heavily cached. Sometimes there's different numbers for the different tabs.)

Comment: This is very interesting... I had started working on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics/89911#89911) using SEDE, and my results there were *higher* (like, 50% higher) than on the site for the C# tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a bug in the SQL here (recently overhauled this page so on average it should be much faster).  The count being show was the total number of tags on unanswered questions, rather than strictly the question count due to those joins.

This will be fixed in the next build (though the tag/total counts on the right are cached live/stale for 15/45 minutes on Stack Overflow...due to the volume of data that goes into them).

Answer (score 2):

I think the high number is the total number of questions that do not have an accepted answer.  That's been hovering around 50% for SO for quite a while, the value matches (833k vs 1.6M questions).

It's been acknowledged for quite a while that a question without an accepted answer is still considered answered if it has posts that got upvotes by other users.  The OP's opinion is deprecated here.  The Unanswered button follows suit, it filters the subset of questions without an accepted answer for questions with answers that got no upvote at all.  The reminder is displayed in orange.  The lower number in your measurement.  But yes, that displayed number is borked.  Counting properly remains an elusive feature at SE.