# Does Stack Overflow measure aborted 'Ask Question' attempts?

Tags: discussion, metrics

Curiosity: Does Stack Overflow in any way keep track of questions that are attempted to be asked, but are never submitted, likely because the 'Related Questions' helped them in some way?  Of those that make it through there, does Stack Overflow keep any metrics on questions that end up being closed because of duplication?

If Stack Overflow reports on that information, what are the metrics on those?

Comment: You can propose to find out the latter [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We do not currently track this.

It's a good idea, though.

Comment: Note that I often create a new question for the sole purpose of finding a question that is a (near) duplicate of some other question which could then be closed as a duplicate. I suspect that more people besides me do this, in which case there could be quite a bit of "false" data about aborted questions.

Comment: @Bart: I don't think it's "false" as such, it's still relevant. But analyzing how many of those enter just the title or just a body might also be interesting.

Comment: @Joachim, you're right, "false" wasn't the best choice of words. The point I was more trying to make is that not all (quite a few?) aborted **Ask Questions** clicks are from people that came to ask a question.

Comment: @Bart: I do the same as you do, and also I sometimes put something in the _body_, just to look at the preview and test some formatting.

Comment: Yeah, I've often thought this would be interesting.