# Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, views, referrals

[A question I flippantly answered a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599680/ive-caught-an-exception-now-what) literally blew up today, gaining me a Skeetian amount of rep for a single question in a single day.

Is there a way to determine *why* this happened?  I immediately wondered who was referring clickers to this question, but is that even possible?  Or is there another way<sup>*</sup>?

<sub>* Goog'd but didn't see anything</sub>

Comment: I've wanted this for a long time - I wouldn't be surprised if I've mentioned it before here, but I'm glad that this is finally an official feature request

Comment: Funny, I was looking at the same question, but this is hardly the first time I've seen similar events. Once Scott Hanselman linked to a post in a tweet and it pulled in something like 30 new votes. It was sheer luck then that I figured out where they came from.

Comment: The answer in this specific case, by the way, [is reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/itnco/at_least_theyre_not_using_on_error_resume_next/).

Comment: @Charles: Thanks.  Thought it probably would be something like this.\

Comment: Fwiw, I think this would be an awesome feature to give to 20Kers (or 30Kers, to give the gamers something else to work for).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258814/163135

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I hear you: just today I had four upvotes to an answer I wrote over a year ago, and it would be awesome to have a way to find where the traffic driving those votes and others like them is coming from. I had just finished my own (now-deleted) feature-request and someone pointed me here (odd that your question didn't show in a search on "referrer").

Here are some additional thoughts:

To prevent referrer spam, this information should only be shown via an ajax request (those specifically asking for it) and only available to those with at least a certain amount of rep. If you want to get fancy, more rep could give you the right to see more history, though that is hardly necessary.

I also considered filtering the stored information: perhaps not showing/saving referrers from within the SE network or Google, but after some thought I think it's better to be able to also see Google searches leading to a question and to preserve the chain within the network if other questions are pointing to this one.  Another rejected idea is that this could only be shown to those with a vested interest (ie: post) in a specific question, but that would end up encouraging wrong behaviors (junk posts just to get referrers).

To be useful, you would want to at minimum be able to see a list of referrers today so that you can perhaps find and interact with whatever source is driving this traffic while it's still relevant.  Additionally, all links into a question page (including direct answer links) should be aggregated together and any significant referrer should be available (even if it's a little stale), where significant is defined as has driven at least some number of views to the question.

Comment: So is there such a "referrer" feature? I was thinking that another use for that is to comb that information and create libraries of features that have answers on the site(s)

Comment: There is an analytics page that shows some of this information, but it's only available to moderators.

Answer (score 6):

The same thing happened to me a while back; it was due to [an "interesting stuff on SO from last month" sort of blog post](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2010/08/05/Interesting+answers+on+Stack+Overflow+from+July) linking to the answer, but I was mystified at first because Google didn't pick up the blog entry for a while. Eventually I got curious, tried again, found the entry, allowing me to both satisfy my curiosity and thank the blogger. :]

So if you wait a few days and try again you might be able to turn up the source on Google.

Comment: Sam Saffron is [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles), the SE developer. Just in case you hadn't realised ;)

Comment: @Farseeker: Aha! Ok, thanks. I knew he worked for SE, but not what his display name on Meta was.