# Is it possible to find out from where a post was linked?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question)

Someone recently linked an answer I wrote on stackoverflow.  I was curious from where it was linked.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get that data?

Comment: How do you know it was linked?

Comment: I'd say Google is the fastest way. Afaik Stack Overflow can't really keep track of external links pointing to it.

Comment: I suspect it was linked because it was sitting at 13 and then it jumped to 36 in the span of 12 hours after being originally posted on July 16.

Comment: Lots of things can drive traffic to a question. With 23 new views, what kind of web site would you expect a link to only drive that much traffic?

Comment: No, not 23 new view, ~23~ 26 new upvotes, somewhere in the vicinity of 10,000-15,000 new views.

Comment: Ah, I see. Expressing units along with numbers is always helpful. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I don't know if SE *does* keep track (but I would, if traffic is that important), but surely [the HTTP REFERER header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) gives such details for many cases.

Comment: The answer is Reddit.  Always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a feature request for that: [Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question)

[TOPSY has some Twitter trackback details](http://topsy.com/stackoverflow.com/questions/11499409/dev-zero-or-dev-random-what-is-more-secure-and-why), and I guess there's similar sites that to do the same for Reddit and the like.

[image]

A search on Reddit itself shows [a mention](http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/y30r9/the_nsa_is_not_going_to_read_deleted_files_from) for the above example too.

Comment: Nice find! Also, the question got edited which means back to the front for some time.

Comment: Still, [you want Jeff to tweet](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1893/over-243-000-views-in-3-days). ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499409/dev-zero-or-dev-random-what-is-more-secure-and-why) was linked [from reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/y30r9/the_nsa_is_not_going_to_read_deleted_files_from/) and got some attention there, resulting in quite a few views and votes (16,032 referrals from reddit today).

Is it possible for us to see the referrers for our traffic? Yes.  Is it cheap? No.  There's [*a lot*](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) of HTTP log data (~50 GB/day storing just the top attributes we care about) and running queries on it isn't lightning fast...so I wouldn't imagine we'll expose this data in any kind of real-time way.  Exposing something like a daily aggregate view would be *possible*, but not a quick development effort and way, way down the priority list (lots of big fish frying back in the kitchen at the moment).

I can't say for sure we'll ever expose this data in the UI, but as far as is it *possible*? yeah sure. Just remember most things are *possible*, but there are costs to every feature as well.

Comment: Aha, not cheap. Isn't that a status declined then for [Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question)

Comment: @Arjan - so it's not *completely* a declined, there is data that's cheap from when *you* link a question, e.g. `/q/123/<userid>`, that's stored in the site's database with referrer as well...we could potentially show that at some point with proper indexing.  As for the general purpose logs? Yeah that's a no for several reasons, not the least of which being we punish that DB server severely when querying older than 7 days (PCIe SSD vs. massive spinny disk array switch over).