# See what links to an answer/question

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question)

So I started getting points for a year old answer all of a sudden and it got me curious. What happened? Did someone just provide a link to my answer? Why the sudden intrest in my answer, or perhaps the question?

Is there a way to see this information? I dont think so. I can see related questions to the right, but not incoming links from other questions/answers. Right?

If there is another question/answer that links to mine, then that may be of intrest. Knowing that users may read the question/answer from a different perspective I could alter the text to better provide information.