# Stats for questions that were shared by users

Tags: support, statistics, sharing

When a question does not have any answers, we see this below the question:

> [image: Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter or Facebook]

Are there any statistics about who shared and what questions have been shared?

Comment: I have rewritten the question, to fit as a support question.

Comment: Related, though not a duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-that-moderators-can-access-for-individual-que

Comment: There is a PostHistoryType called *Tweeted* (id=25) but the [PostHistory table doesn't have any rows](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203960)

Comment: @rene The [SO twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackfeed) appears to have been inactive for 2+ years now. If you [re-run the query on an SE 2.0 site](http://data.stackexchange.com/japanese/query/203960), you'll get results. (Of course, this is data about automatic tweeting by the SE tweetbots - not about sharing by regular users.)

Comment: @senshin Ah, nice, didn't know that...

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question

Answer (score 1):

When you share a post by clicking the 'share' button, you get a url that includes your user ID in the URL:

> `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234559/209637`

The numbers after the last slash correspond to the User ID of the person who shared it, in this case, it's my user ID:

> `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209637/jmac`

These do get tracked, and a query is regularly run on the SE side to assign badges:

- [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) (25 referrals)
- [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) (300 referrals)
- [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) (1000 referrals)

Since these queries look at unique IP addresses, the query has to look at [PII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information), which is not shared publicly according to our [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).

So yes, it is possible to track, and is tracked, but is not made public for that reason.

Since all the links to various social networks use that same URL, there is no way to be certain where the question actually came from originally. If I tweet something that someone shares on their Facebook, even if we do detect that a user came from a Facebook link, we have no way of knowing which social network the link was originally shared to. I'm not sure how much of that data is stored, and how it's stored (if it is), but chances are that stats beyond the badges isn't readily available if at all.

Comment: What I'd like is the ability to see common referrers.

Comment: @Codes, would you mind editing your question to be more specific about what it is you want to know then?