# Can we have access to the statistical information about click behavior on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, usability

Is there a way to get statistical info about click behavior on SE? What links do SE users visit: Questions, tags, StackExchange, User page, ... When, in what sequence?

This info would be of great help to formulate / test Graphical User Interface changes on SE.

Joel wrote about [Usability Testing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/UsabilityTestingwithMorae.html), and SE doesn't need that as they already have the log files that can be mined (by their trusted worker, not by outsiders).

To be specific, I'd like to know the number of times somebody clicks on StackExchange and then on Inbox (to establish the [clickonomics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98368/clickonomics-on-se) proposal). As this data is already available to the SE dev team, it could be mined.

**Edit** It would be nice to have that statistical info available so people can look for other improvements as well.

Comment: Currently, I think only pageviews are tracked at the web server level.

Comment: @Jon, would be nice to have 'access' to that data in some way.

Comment: Related: [Stack Exchange Community Statistics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics). (But no cigar there, given @Jon's comment above.)

Comment: @Arjan, great link!

Comment: And [the public Quantcast statistics](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com) are not specific enough either.