# Do multiple edits on the same post count?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

Do multiple edits on the same post count towards the editor badges?

Related : [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/165097) , but doesn't talk about multiple edits on the same post.

Answer (score 5):

The Copy Editor and Strunk & White badges count post *revisions*, so yes, multiple edits on the same post do count.

Here is a SEDE query I created that matches* the SQL running in the real badge-awarding script (at least at the time I indirectly obtained it through [this project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics)). I don't believe the behaviour has changed since then.

[How many Copy Editor/Strunk & White-qualifying edits have I made?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1397/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made)

<sub>* The real query has to exclude deleted posts and return a list of users that don't have the badge yet, while the SEDE query doesn't need to exclude deleted content (because it doesn't exist in the data dump), and filters by a single user.</sub>

Comment: I agree the badge description is a bit confusing given this, but (a) most people would probably only be editing a given post once, and (b) try to explain this all in a tiny badge description. :)

Comment: I like that link you gave, but I don't know what exactly is my UserId Can you please help? or anyone?

Comment: @Thursagen: Go to your user profile. The user id will appear in the URL after **/users/** (you should see a number) as well as on the **search** text box on the rightmost top corner. Note: User ids are different for each site. So, if you need SO user id, you should be in your SO's profile page. And same goes for Meta.

Comment: @siva, cheers mate!

Comment: It keeps on giving me Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@Thursagen8183". Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId". Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId"

Comment: What do I actually enter, "User:8183/Thursagen"?

Comment: @Thursagen: Which site edit count would you like to see?

Comment: My English.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Thursagen: Just the number **8183**. That's your user id.

Comment: @Siva, it worked! Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: It gave me zero

Comment: @Thursagen: Please refer my answer (my answer is **wrong** though), I have just added steps to find your edits count in a different way.