# Community Voting Statistics of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, voting, statistics, trends

Please forgive if the question has been asked and answered before (I did a search and did not find anything conclusive) but is there some place I can go to view voting statistics for Stack Overflow?

I would like to see statistics/graphs of voting trends in recent history compared to when the site was less popular. [Some of the 'answers' to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics) would seem to offer such statistics but I did not see a follow up link to the actual statistics suggested (other then a graph related to the statistics of the sportsmanship badge).

Comment: Have you had a look at [the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Such stats are available to mods, but I'm pretty sure there are some relevant Data Explorer queries. For example: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72815/voting-comparisons-arranged-by-day-of-the-week

Comment: I have some data explorer queries that measure user participation linked in [this answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3140/1130) if you want to copy them. It should be noted when working with DataExplorer that deleted posts aren't included, and close/reopen votes expire so don't bother querying those :)

Comment: @Rachel thanks for that link, and your thorough analysis of programmers SE. Have you done a similar analysis of SO? I have a suspicion that as the number of questions has increased (as the site has gained popularity) the number of votes has not kept up. Thus lots of decent to good questions with little to no votes. Thoughts?

Comment: @droid I think I did check out SO's numbers once, but it was a long time ago. You can run saved queries on another site fairly easily though and look at the graphs to see how they differ

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/607410#graph) that shows the voting (up/down/accept) trends for Stack Overflow:

```sql
select year(v.creationdate)
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as accepted
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 2 and posttypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Q upmod]
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 3 and posttypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Q downmod]
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 2 and posttypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [A upmod]
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 3 and posttypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [A downmod]
from posts p 
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where votetypeid in (1,2,3)
group by year(v.creationdate)
```

And as a picture tells you more then words, here is the graph:

[image: voting trends]