# statistics on the questions/answers/user accounts removal

Tags: discussion, data-dump, statistics, research

Is there some kind of statistics on the questions/answers/user accounts removal on Stack Overflow?

As a researcher I would like to consider the [Stack Overflow data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) as a representation of the activity of the Stack Overflow participants. However, the fact that [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)/[accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) can be deleted means that this representation is incomplete. While incompleteness is, as such, not a new issue on its own, it would be great to have an estimate of *how incomplete* is the data.

(I've checked the [Community Statistics discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics) from 2011 but it seems that deletion was not considered when not related to migration to other network sites.)

Comment: Related: [Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the addition of the table [`postswithdeleted`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se) in SEDE we can reliable answer the question about visible and deleted posts. There is only meta-data available, like type of post and deletion date. The other fields are emptied.

For the users we can only do a guesstimate based on the assumption that the primarykey column `id` of the users table is a sequence that started at 1 and increases with 1 for every new user. The sequence is generated by Microsoft Sql Server and it is known that it sometimes jumps in the sequence. By subtracting the count(*) from max(id) we get an estimate how many users are deleted.

Based on above explanation I've created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/631997) to give you the rough numbers for removed data from the dataset:

```sql
select case when posttypeid = 1 then 'Question' else 'Answer'end as [Stat type]
     , sum(case when deletiondate is null then 1 else 0 end) [not deleted] 
     , sum(case when deletiondate is null then 0 else 1 end) [deleted] 
     , count(*) [total]
from postswithdeleted
where posttypeid in (1,2)
group by posttypeid
union 
select 'Users '
   , count(*) [# of users]
   , max(id) - count(*) [est. # of deleted users]
   , null
from users
```

When run today the results of above query are:

[image: statistics on what is deleted]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.